# Moment.js countdown not decrementing more than a second

Tags: javascript, momentjs, countdown

I'm using moment.js to create a three minute countdown. However, every time the page loads, the timer decrements by one second and stops at 2:59. Printing out variables such as `future` and `difference` seems to yield normal results, however, so I believe that my error lies in the countdown. What is wrong with my countdown?

Here's my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var now = moment();
            var future = moment(now).add(3, 'm');
            var difference = future - now;
            var duration = moment.duration(difference, 's');
            var interval = 1000;

            setInterval(function() {
                if(duration.asSeconds() <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(intervalId);
                    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = moment(duration.asSeconds()).format("m:s");
                }

                duration = moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() - 1, 's');
                document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = moment(duration.asSeconds()).format("m:s");
            }, interval);
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change that to be something like this:

`if (moment.duration(future - moment()).asSeconds() <= 0) {`

and change

`duration = moment.duration(duration.asSeconds() - 1, 's');`

to be

`duration = moment.duration(moment.duration(future - moment()).asSeconds(), 's');`

because you're closure is capturing the value of `duration` above but never really updating it.

Comment: Using duration.toString() to print out the result, I get PT2M59S instead of 3:00. However, it does seem to be decrementing.

Comment: that's because durations conform to ISO 8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals   if you want it in a formatted string you can use `humanize()` http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: I'm sorry, but `humanize()` creates something like `3 minutes`. I'm looking for a clock that can countdown each second, updating every second.